# Replying to old chat conversations

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, reply

I couldn't use the `reply to this message` to a chat message that is a day old. Why is this? I had to resort to typing `@username` so as to grab the person's attention.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you know the chat transcript URL, you can do this instead:

> example url: http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/620858#620858

enter the chatroom in question (since this came from the tavern, I would go to the tavern) and in the message box key the following:

```
:620858 message
```

notice the space after the `:nnnnnn`

In this manner, you can reply to any message, no matter how old, provided the message has not been deleted. At least, that's how I do it.

Comment: sorry for my ignorance about this, is it really a bug?

Comment: @ianace No, it's about how you got to that message. It can only do a reply "within the chatroom" and not "on the transcript". There's no interface for it to do the second page. There is an interface to do it on the first one.

Answer (score 2):

Although I'm not 100% sure what your precise issue was, I think this is fixed since [replying from the transcript is now possible](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117271/add-the-ability-to-reply-to-a-chat-message-directly-from-the-transcript).

Answer (score 0):

Press `Ctrl+F5` on your browser to refresh the page and load all the scripts then try again. It should work.

Comment: i was actually following from my stack exchange notification which redirected me to the chat message. i think its not about scripts being outdated, its just that the notification directs me to an archive which just 1 day old