# Add the ability to reply to a chat message directly from the transcript

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, chat

Notifications of new messages in chat land in the global inbox and the links take you to the chat transcript. This is fine, but a lot of my chat communication involves asking other moderators questions, so I often get replies long after I'm gone from chat.

I usually want to respond to what they told me or answer one of their questions and there isn't a way to easily do that from the transcript since responding to a specific message involves looking up its ID in the permalink, clicking the "join this room" button and then pasting the chat message ID in the text box.

I think this could be simplified by adding the reply arrow to transcript messages. Clicking it would make the user join the chat room and prepopulate the chat message ID they're replying to in the chat box, as if the arrow had been clicked from within the room.

Comment: YES. Why didn't I ask for this months ago?

Comment: @MatthewRead - Possibly because you saw [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90902/replying-to-old-chat-conversations)?  The accepted answer to that question (which is tagged as a bug)an explanation from  jcolebrand's of the gyrations required to do it manually.  +1 for the feature request, though, the manual method shouldn't be necessary.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This makes a lot of sense, so to prevent more people from spending precious meta rep on bounties here, it's now implemented. The transcript doesn't have the "quick action" icons on messages, so you'll have to go through the popup menu:

[image: transcript message menu with reply link]

– but other than that, it does exactly what you suggested.

Comment: :122168 Cool people remember the chat message ID

Comment: LOL, I like that some people spent rep on a bounty for this answer :D

Answer (score 17):

I have no way of influencing this request whatsoever, so here you go:

[image: narwhal]

Comment: NICE!  I'll call him "Tinkles"!

Comment: Will you just let it auto-accept @Won't? Don't you have a heart?

Comment: Huh?  What you mean?  I have no idea what's going on.  Excuse me, I have to go shine my bowling ball.