# Post date in chat message popup?

Tags: feature-request, chat

Communicating through chat would be a bit smoother if it was easier to tell how old a message was.  Knowing the age of the message allows the user to decide whether they need to scan the transcript or if they can immediately reply.

People can @ you in a chat message when you aren't in the room, and that will eventually generate a notification that goes in your inbox.  That's great.  When you click on the link, you are taken to the transcript where that message can be found.  Awesome.  But there is no easy way to determine how long ago it happened.

It would be nice if we could check to see how old the message was.  If the message is brand new, you can just jump into the chat room and reply (or hopefully in the near future [reply directly from the transcript](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117271/add-the-ability-to-reply-to-a-chat-message-directly-from-the-transcript)).  If its older, you may want to scan the transcript to see what else was said regarding the message subject.

I'd suggest, in the transcript, that the message popup box contain the date of the post

[image]

Somewhere near the narwhal.  Oh, and there should be a picture of a narwhal as well.

Comment: Is the narwhal wearing a hat, or is that a red pancake? I hope it is not a bagel, and somebody is not using the narwhal to play horseshoes launch (which should be "bagels launch on a narwhal corn," in this case).