# Could we have quick actions in the chat transcript?

Tags: feature-request, chat

I like that we have a [reply option from the transcript](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/122168/205264), but I'd like to ask if we could have this in a similar way as on the normal chat (like with what balpha refers to as 'quick actions')?

I didn't know it was possible to reply right from the transcript until I saw the linked meta post.

Balpha says:

> The transcript doesn't have the "quick action" icons on messages, so you'll have to go through the popup menu:

But I don't understand why there can't be quick action icons on messages in the transcript. Is there a reason for that? If not, could we have it please? I'm getting tired of clicking that extra click.