# Make ability to reply to chat transcript more clearly visible

Tags: feature-request, chat, user-interface, usability

Until just recently, I did not realize you could [reply to a chat transcript](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/117271/193412).

I have always used the arrow at the end of each line to reply and never use the dropdown.

These are the buttons I use:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

In a chat transcript, this "reply" button disappears. However you *can* still reply if you click on the message "popout" here:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

My assumption was this referred to the buttons on the right. However it seems this is actually clickable! I could have saved myself tons of time in finding the message ID and manually adding the reply message.

Can these buttons be enabled on the transcript, too, since they are just as functional there?

The UI is inconsistent and it is probable many other people are unaware you actually reply directly in a transcript.

Comment: I don't get it: what “buttons on the right” are you talking about? How is the UI inconsistent? The menu is exactly the same in the live chat and in the transcript except for the reduced flagging options from the transcript.