# Can we get a way to enable chat notifications from a room where we have not been active in the last 7 days?

Tags: feature-request, chat, notifications, ping

If a user pings me in a chat room, I get a notification if I was active in that room [in the last 7 days](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/939) (is this really how it works? It is strange that this information does not appear [in the FAQs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/319353/643262)...)

I am a member of a couple of chat rooms that get activity less often than that. As a result of the lack of notifications, I sometimes miss important messages related to moderation (the rooms are moderator-only and for moderation purposes. But the lack of notifications may be a problem for other kinds of low-activity rooms). I would like to be able to "follow" a specific room, so that I always get notified when someone pings me in that room. This should ideally be a private setting (such that other users do not take advantage of it to send me spam), and it should be possible to "unfollow" the room at any time.

**Is there a way/workaround to enable unconditional notifications of pings from a specific chat room? If not, can we get one?**

Comment: The person writing the chat message who wants to ping you should know at the time they are writing their message if you are pingable in that room or not. If your username is included in the auto-complete list for `@` pings., then you are pingable. If your username is not in the auto-complete list, then you're not `@` pingable. In order to notify you about a new message, all the user needs to do is *actually reply* to an earlier message of yours. Replying to an old message will always notify you, even if the message being replied to is years old and you haven't been in the room for years.

Comment: It's probably not really satisfactory, but this is what I use to get attention of a specific user who is not pingable using `@username`: [Does a direct reply to a message in chat create a notification, no matter what age the message is?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/287972) (After posting this, I have noticed that this was [mentioned in a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/363236/can-we-get-a-way-to-enable-chat-notifications-from-a-room-where-we-have-not-been#comment1212122_363238) under the answer.)

Answer (score 4):

The workaround would be to add the room to your favorites, and rejoin your favorited rooms regularly/each day, or have a pinned browser tab on your favorite device(s) with that room that opens whenever you start your browser (then, use the browser regularly).

By making sure you join the room regularly/every day, you meet the criteria balpha outlined in the [post you linked](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/939/89529), people can ping you, and you'll get the inbox notification.

Additionally, for these rooms that are moderator-only, you could make a gentlemen's agreement with everyone in there to superping people instead of using regular @mentions, so that there will always be a notification.

Comment: superping only works for mods, not for regulars, right?

Comment: @rene yes. wimi specifically mentions these rooms are moderator-only, so it should work for this specific use-case. :)

Comment: @Tinkeringbell some of the rooms are private chats with a regular user (so moderator-only plus one regular user). In that case, a non-superping solution is necessary. Good that you mention both cases!

Comment: In public rooms, you could also make an informal agreement among regulars to reply to old messages of yours instead of using a direct @mention.

Comment: @wimi If it's a private room with one other user but you don't use the room for a week, the room gets frozen automatically, so they wouldn't be able to ping you anyway - though, perhaps you mean a public or gallery room and not a "private" room?